# Ember Select-view error: Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array

Tags: ember.js

I want to simply render an Ember select view with the model defined in a route. Data is coming from fixtures adapter.  When doing this, I receive the error: Ember.CollectionView's content must implement Ember.Array - You passed App.AuthorsController.

How can I solve this ?

See JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/frvJZ/4/

(after running the app, click on the 'Authors' link to goto the authors route with authorsController data.

**CODE-HTML:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>Ember select view</h1>

    {{#linkTo 'authors'}}Authors{{/linkTo}}

    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="authors">
     {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.AuthorsController"}}
</script>
```

**CODE-JS:**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('authors', { path: "/authors" });
});

App.AuthorsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Author.find();
  }
});

App.AuthorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({})


//DATA

//define model for category
App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    language: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

App.Author.FIXTURES = [
 {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Luc Verschuren',
    language: 'German'
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Patrick Burms',
    language: 'Dutch'
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   name: 'Jean Demeester',
   language: 'French'
 }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `content` property of your `App.AuthorsController` having the data:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="authors">
 {{view Ember.Select 
   contentBinding="content"
   optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
</script>
```

Working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyclomarc/frvJZ/4/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This indeed works ! I am always confused about the difference between App.AuthorsController, content and model.  Many thanks !

Comment: @Marc, glad I could help, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you want, so future folks will know it worked for you

Comment: This indeed works if the select view can be based on "content". But what to do when I also want to show for example another select list that needs to be rendered with other data.  See http://jsfiddle.net/frvJZ/10/ -  In this example I also want to show a select view with all the AuthorTypes (defined as fixture data).  Any help would be much appreciated !